# use script.alicio.us for color picker -> php GD

Tags: php, gd, javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want to use a color picker to pick two colors and then draw a rectangle with a gradient using the two colors, via php/GD.

I'm currently working with prototype.js/script.alicio.us

So, two color picker html fields:

```
<form>
<p>color 1 #<input type="text" id="colorfield1" value="FF33FF"></p>
<p>color 2 #<input type="text" id="colorfield2" value="CC3366"></p>
</p>
</form>
```

With prototype.js, it looks like I need to create some kind of event listener and then trigger off my php script from that.

I think it should look a little bit like this, but am not certain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  Event.observe('colorfield1', 'submit', what goes here???);
  Event.observe('colorfield2 , 'submit', what goes here???);
});
</script>
```

I'm using this color picker code: 
http://code.google.com/p/colorpickerjs/

Comment: Must it be PHP? You can save a request to the server by using [CSS gradients](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) - although that's currently only about [55% supported](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients), IE is slow to adopt.

Comment: What would be the reason for using CSS gradients, especially if only 55% supported?

Comment: I don't know the details but you might be building an app that is already dependent on modern HTML5 features. In that case the adoption would be much higher, almost 100% of your target audience. The advantages of doing it client-side would be speed and simplicity.

Comment: Not using HTML5 yet. This is a "developer tool" application I"m building to help me create color schemes & ui look/feel for a hardware platform, where I would update the colors & graphics on my webserver and (after a few seconds) see the results on my device's screen when it does a refresh call. Seems to me the big push these days is to offload the work to the server or cloud (amazon Fire for example), not the client, which might be some slow out of date old hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @clockworkgeek about trying to do this client-side, but if I understand you correctly, you could do this with ajax like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  Event.observe('colorfield1', 'submit', doFormSubmit);
  Event.observe('colorfield2 , 'submit', doFormSubmit);
});

function doFormSubmit(event) {
  // fire off an ajax request/updater, sending along the values
  // in colorfield1 and colorfield2
  new Ajax.Updater('myImageDisplay', '/myPhpScript.php', {
    parameters: {
      colorfield1: $F('colorfield1'),
      colorfield2: $F('colorfield2')
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

This will make a request to your php script with the data from the input fields. Be sure to check out the documentation for [Ajax Updater](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/) to see if this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, Ajax is what I want to use. Is there some reason not to use server side scripts to create .png files?

Comment: The biggest concern is latency between asking for, processing, and returning the png. If you could tweak some css instead of needing an ajax request, you could handle this all on the front end and the app would feel more responsive/immediate.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked it looks like the `onClose` event will be most useful. (`onUpdate` will fire too often.)

If you are generating an image server-side then it makes sense to use an image element instead of AJAX.

```
<form>
    <p>color 1 #<input type="text" id="colorfield1" value="FF33FF"></p>
    <p>color 2 #<input type="text" id="colorfield2" value="CC3366"></p>
    <img src="" id="gradient" />
</form>
```

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    new Control.ColorPicker('colorfield1', { onClose: update });
    new Control.ColorPicker('colorfield2', { onClose: update });
});

function update(event)
{
    // `this` is the input field
    var url = this.form.action;
    url += (action.indexOf('?') < 0 ? '?' : '&') + this.form.serialize();
    $('gradient').writeAttribute('src', url);
}
```